# Is there any way to make a custom addon or modifier which contains multiple modifier easily?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, add-on

I make a mesh with multiple modifiers. Is there any way to copy those modifiers to another mesh in another project easily just like add-ons did (one-click apply)? Is that thing can be done in blender 3.0.0?

Answer (score 3):

You can append the mesh into the new project, select the others new meshes which should get the modifiers stack, shift select the appended one (it has to be the active one, highlighted in yellow, while others objects highlighted in orange) then press Ctrl C, Copy selected modifiers, enable the modifiers you want to copy and confirm.

Default Blender "Copy attributes menu" addon has to be enabled in the preferences panel.

[image]

Comment: + or instead of appending you can get familiar with Asset Manager features :)